# Trying to solve a complicated equation system

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have a complicated equation system that I try to solve.

```
paramFinal = {σ -> 2.5, ρ -> 1.5, a -> 2.5, δ -> 0.00001, γ -> 0.001, ψ -> 1, h -> 90, θ -> 0.15, y -> 1, cmin -> 0.01};
```

I try to solve the two equation system by NSolve

```
adap[β_, root22_] := (1 - root22) root22 - ((γ a)^(1 - 1/σ) (σ (1 - Exp[-(β - ρ) h]))/(β - ρ))/(a - δ) ((-θ/(ρ + (y - θ root22)) ((((a - δ) (1 -root22) root22)/(γ a))^(1 - σ)/(((σ (1 -Exp[-(β - ρ) h]))/(β - ρ))^-σ (1 - σ)) - cmin ((1 - Exp[-(β - (ρ)) h])/(β - (ρ))) - (y - θ root22) ψ ) - ψ θ)/((1 - 2 root22) - (ρ + (y - θ root22)))/((a - δ) - (ρ + (y - θ root22))))^(-(1/σ))
```

Normally, I can solve this system by FindRoot (when I attribute a value for $\beta$, I can find $root22$) but the problem is that I would like to make a list for different values of $\beta$ and $root22$ in the following way ;

```
solK[i_] := NSolve[adap[β, i] == 0, {β}, Reals];

Table[solK[i], {i, 0.41, 0.47, 0.5}]
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica does not give any result and stuck in Running... mode. Any hints or suggestions in order to make this list ?

Comment: It looks like the difference between this question and its answer is the use of `NSolve` versus `FindRoot`.  It might be nice for someone to post a "canonical" Q&A about the difference between these two functions.

Answer (score 1):

This gives very fastly the answer to the problem ;

```
Table[{FindRoot[(1 - root22) root22 - ((γ a)^(1 - 1/σ) (σ (1 - Exp[-(β - ρ) h]))/(β - ρ))/(a - \δ) ((-θ/(ρ + (y - θ root22)) ((((a - \δ) (1 - root22) root22)/(γ a))^(1 - σ)/(((σ (1 - Exp[-(β - ρ) h]))/(β - ρ))^-\σ (1 - σ)) - cmin ((1 - Exp[-(β - (ρ)) h])/(β - (ρ))) - \(y - θ root22) ψ ) - ψ θ)/((1 - 2 root22) - (ρ + (y - θ root22)))/((a - \δ) - (ρ + (y - θ root22))))^(-(1/σ)) == 0 /. paramFinal, {β, 1.6}]}, {root22, 0.001, 0.99, 0.01}]
```